# Build Extjs 4.2 application without Ext Libraries

Tags: extjs, build, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

Is there is any way to build Extjs 4.2 application without including the Ext libraries. Till now I have used sencha cmd to generate and build my app. But now the Ext libraries are on server side and I have to build my application without including Ext libraries. 
Can I do it using Sencha cmd or any other tool?
Kindly help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'build an ExtJs application without ExtJs libraries'? Sounds like 'write a letter without letters'

Comment: @lorenz I agree it sounds foolish, but this is my requirement now. Our client wants us to build app without libraries, and what ever outcome will come (which will be application code concatenated and compressed), they will use it and Extjs Libraries which is on there server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is (Ext JS library being "on the server") but yes, you [can build an Ext JS application without Sencha Cmd](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/getting_started/welcome_to_extjs.html) (example is for v5.1, but applies to all versions).

**In order to use Sencha Cmd, you do need a copy of the SDK locally.** I'm not sure why you can't simply copy it to your local machine (it should be checked into your SVN/Git/etc repo...), but you don't need Sencha Cmd to build a Sencha application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thing is that while the building process is going on, I want to exclude all Extjs libraries which become part of built version. 
Can you help me with this? Using Sencha CMD to build such version is not a requirement. Any solution will work